# How can I get my Hostinger shared hosting server to execute .htaccess file in hidden /.well-known folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, shared-hosting

I am on a Hostinger shared plan, trying to set a CORS header on a single TOML file that MUST reside in the public_html/.well-known folder. I have an .htaccess file in the ".well-known" folder but the Apache server will not process it.

However, if I rename the ".well-known" folder to "well-known" (just removing the period), the .htaccess file works and I can set whatever headers I want for files in that folder.

At this point I have deleted my entire site and replaced it with an extremely simple one in order to try and make this work.

**The current file structure is as follows:**

```
public_html
  /.well-known
    .htaccess
    test.toml
  /well-known
    .htaccess
    test.toml
  index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Apache Header Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Apache Header Test
  </body>
</html>
```

**.htaccess   (identical in the ".well-known" and "well-known" folders)**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

**test.toml   (identical in the ".well-known" and "well-known" folders)**

```
Apache Header Test
```

When I navigate to /well-known/test.toml, the response is served with the CORS header set and a content-type of "text-plain", and the toml file contents show as plain text in Chrome, which is the desired and expected behavior for both folders.

However when I navigate to /.well-known/test.toml (with the period), there is no CORS header, it shows a content-type of "application/octet-stream", and the toml file downloads instead of showing in the browser.

What exactly is happening here and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Since you are on a shared host, you'll need to contact your hosting support. It's quite possible that your host has put restrictions on the `/.well-known` subdirectory (since this folder has a special purpose) and you are unlikely to be able to override this in `.htaccess`. If, for instance, they have completely disabled `.htaccess` overrides for this specific directory then this can only be re-enabled in the main server config. Does this apply to any dot-folder? Or only `.well-known`? What if you have a `.well-known` folder in a different location? (Not that this will help you).

Comment: What's the relevance of the `index.html` file in your example? Incidentally, `application/octet-stream` is not a default mime-type, so something would seem to be explicitly setting this (for this folder).

Comment: After going back and forth with Hostinger about this all day yesterday they told me to try StackOverflow haha. Anyhow I just took your suggestion and tried with a ```./test``` folder and setting the header worked! So I will contact them right now and ask them specifically if they disabled .htaccess overrides for just the ```/.well-known``` folder. By the way the ```index.html``` file isn't really relevant, except I guess to show that I didn't have any extra scripts running and had the site as basic as could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finally asking the right question to Hostinger (thank you MrWhite!), they confirmed that making changes to the `/.well-known` folder is not possible on a shared hosting plan. Here is the official response I received:

*The .well-known directory is server-default, so that is why overriding and making changes to it is not possible on a shared hosting plan, as important data/information is stored there.
To make meaningful changes in this directory, you would need root access, which is only available on our VPS plans.*